# AngularJS script moving to production

Tags: angularjs

There is the following code :

```
angular.module('app.services', []).factory('authService', ['SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT', 'SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT', '$http', '$cookieStore', (SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT, $http, $cookieStore) ->
    auth = {}
    auth.signIn = (credentials) ->
        return $http.post(SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT, { user: credentials }).then (response, status) ->
            $cookieStore.put('user', response.data)
    auth.signOut = ->
        return $http.delete(SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT).then (response, status) ->
            $cookieStore.remove('user')
    auth.currentUser = ->
        $cookieStore.get('user')

    auth
]).value('SIGN_IN_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in').value('SIGN_OUT_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out').factory('User', ['$resource', 'USERS_ENDPOINT', ($resource, USERS_ENDPOINT) ->
    $resource(USERS_ENDPOINT)
]).value('USERS_ENDPOINT', 'http://localhost:3000/users')
```

As you can see I have some links to my localhost server, but when I move it to the production servers it  won't work. I don't want to hardcode links, because production server may change; I just want use for links current address of the server when this script works. How should I change my script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is. I understand that 'it' doesn't work in production but can you please explain a little bit more on exactly what breaks? You are using coffee script. Does your  tool minimize the Javascript when deploying to production? It is common to have Dependency injection issues with Angular on minification if one is not careful..

Answer (score 0):

Since this data is mostly related to server side, I like to put it inline in a module constant or value. This way you can interpret it server-side and inject into your main app, and you don't have to worry about timing issues etc.

```
// inline
angular.module('Preload',[]).contstant('BASE_URL','http://localhost.foo');

...

// inject
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['Preload']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe local host is not configured in the hosts file. Make sure the following entry is in the `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```